# How would I write the Lodash function orderBy in VanillaJS?

Tags: javascript, sorting, lodash

I see a lot of translations from LoDash to Vanilla JS for the lodash function sortBy(). However, I don't see any for orderBy. How can that function be written in standard Javascript?

Comment: what would be different sort vs order??

Comment: something like _.orderBy(activity, 'count', 'desc') vs 'asc' for that third parameter

Comment: I know this is not really the answer but you could just adjust the sorting function in `sortBy` to accomodate for the various 'asc' and 'desc' parameters

Answer (score 4):

This solution seems to approximate the same functionality:

```
function sortBy (key, cb) {
  if (!cb) cb = () => 0
  return (a, b) => (a[key] > b[key]) ? 1
    : ((b[key] > a[key]) ? -1 : cb(a, b))
}

function sortByDesc (key, cb) {
  if (!cb) cb = () => 0
  return (b, a) => (a[key] > b[key]) ? 1
    : ((b[key] > a[key]) ? -1 : cb(b, a))
}

function orderBy (keys, orders) {
  let cb = () => 0
  keys.reverse()
  orders.reverse()
  for (const [i, key] of keys.entries()) {
    const order = orders[i]
    if (order == 'asc') {
      cb = sortBy(key, cb)
    } else if (order == 'desc') {
      cb = sortByDesc(key, cb)
    } else {
      throw new Error(`Unsupported order "${order}"`)
    }
  }
  return cb
}

// usage:
users.sort( orderBy( ['user', 'age'], ['asc', 'desc'] ) );
```

Source: https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Lodash-Underscore/issues/280#issuecomment-690604745