# How do I write lodash orderBy function in plain typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I want to remove lodash from my project, one of the functions I'm using is orderBy. I followed this post in trying to replace the function: [How would I write the Lodash function orderBy in VanillaJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65689191/how-would-i-write-the-lodash-function-orderby-in-vanillajs), but I'm getting the error message: .reverse is not a function. Here is my implementation:

```
private sortBy(key, cb) {
    if (!cb) cb = () => 0;
    return (a, b) => ((a[key] > b[key]) ? 1 :
        ((b[key] > a[key]) ? -1 : cb(a, b)));
}

private sortByDesc(key, cb) {
    if (!cb) cb = () => 0;
    return (b, a) => ((a[key] > b[key]) ? 1 :
        ((b[key] > a[key]) ? -1 : cb(b, a)));
}

private _orderBy(keys: any[], orders: any[]) {
    let cb :any;
    keys.reverse();
    orders.reverse();
    for (const [i, key] of keys.entries()) {
        const order = orders[i];
        if (order === 'asc') { cb = this.sortBy(key, cb); } else if (order === 'desc') { cb = this.sortByDesc(key, cb); } else throw new Error(`Unsupported order "${order}"`);
    }
    return cb;
}
```

And I'm trying to use it like so:

```
public async getResults<T>(
        sport: SportType,
        linkParam: string,
        linkValue: string,
        groupBy?: string,
        orderBy?: string,
        sortBy?: string,
        facets?: string,
        limit?: number,
        search?: string,
    ): Promise<Data | undefined> {
        const allItems = await this.getResultsbyParamId<T>(
            sport,
            linkParam,
            linkValue,
        );
        const sortedItems =
      !!orderBy &&
      allItems.concat().sort(this._orderBy(orderBy.split(','), !!sortBy && (sortBy.split(',') as ('asc' | 'desc')[])));
        //   _orderBy(
        //       allItems,
        //       orderBy.split(','),
        //       !!sortBy && (sortBy.split(',') as ('asc' | 'desc')[]),
        //   );
        const totalItems = allItems?.length || 0;

        const results = chain(sortedItems || allItems)
            .filter((x) => this.filterItemsBySearchParam<T>(x, search))
            .filter((x) => this.filterItemsByFacets<T>(x, facets))
            .groupBy((x) => (groupBy ? [groupBy.split(',').map((path) => get(x, path))] : ''))
            .map((filteredItems: any, key) => {
                if (!isNaN(Number(limit))) {
                    filteredItems = [...filteredItems.slice(0, limit)];
                }

                return this.addData<T>(key, filteredItems.length, filteredItems);
            })
            .value();

        return this.addMeta(
            results,
            totalItems,
            limit !== 0 ? this.getFacetOptions<T>(allItems) : [],
        );
    }
```

But `orders.reverse();` is throwing that error. (.reverse is not a function). What am I doing wrongly? or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: (Plain typescript seems like an oxymoron)

Comment: How are you calling `getResults`? `orders` isn't going to be an array if `sortBy` is falsy

Comment: Calling it like so:

return await this.resultService.getResults<BoutResult>(
            SportType.grappling,
            'coreEventId',
            coreEventId,
            query.groupBy,
            query.orderBy,
            query.sortBy,
            query.facets,
            query.limit,
            query.search,
        );

Comment: What is the value of `query.sortBy`?